# Is there a way to modify the domain of the heroku session affinity cookie?

Tags: node.js, heroku, session-cookies, session-affinity

On the frontend I am having a domain for example: xyz.com and my backend is having the domain api.xyz.com? When I enabled the session affinity on heroku, it is sending the set-cookie header with the domain api.xyz.com, but since my frontend is on xyz.com the cookie is not getting set in the browser. Is there any way to change the domain value of the session affinity cookie on heroku?
Thanks

I have tried different things, but since the domain value of the cookie is the subdomain of the frontend, the cookie is not getting set